# Swift Bitshift Integers in Array to the Right

Tags: arrays, swift, bit-shift

I've found a similar example in [Python](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/shift-the-bits-of-integer-array-elements-to-the-right-in-numpy).

Essentially, say you have an array which is `[1, 2, 3]`, and in binary that would be `[0b00000001, 0b00000010, 0b00000011]`, what's the fastest way to bitshift that into `[0b00000000, 0b10000001, 0b00000001]`?

Basically bitshifting an array as if it were one huge int. (The left-hand side can always be assumed to be 0.)

Unfortunately I haven't got any code, because I have no clue how to achieve this, sorry!

Comment: Hmm… interesting… I wonder if you could join the array into a string (without the 0b) and then remove the last and add a 0 to the front. Then split into an array again. Not sure though.

Comment: @Fogmeister That would definitely work; however, I forgot to mention that I specifically need to make the algorithm as fast as possible... There would also be a few thousand elements in this array at once..

Comment: Ah ok… something like… iterate the array indices… check parity and store odd/even. Bit shift value to right. Then move to next iteration. Check parity again, temp store. Bit shift to right. If prevParity odd then add the 1 to the front (whichever that number is. Or bitwise OR with 1000000…). Store this parity into prev parity. Move to next iteration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could do it something like this:

```
func bitShift(array: [UInt8]) -> [UInt8] {
  var output = array

  var prevParity = false

  for i in 0..<output.count {
    // check parity of current value and store it
    let tempParity = (output[i] & 1) == 1

    // bitshift the current value to the right
    output[i] = output[i] >> 1

    if prevParity {
      // add on the first one if the previous value was odd
      output[i] = output[i] | 0b10000000
    }

    // store tempParity into prevParity for next loop
    prevParity = tempParity
  }

  return output
}
```

Advanced operators... https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/AdvancedOperators.html

Answer (score 1):

(I do not know Swift!)

```
var bignum = [1, 2, 3]
var carry = 0
let signBit = 1 << 31 // or 1 << 63 or int.min
for i in 00..<bignum.count {
    var n = bignum[i]
    let nextCarry = (n & 1) == 1 ? signBit : 0
    n = (n >> 1) & ~signBit
    if carry {
        n = n | carry
    }
    bignum[i] = n
    carry = nextCarry;
}
```

The sign bit must be set when the prior number was odd (ended with bit 1).

A shift-right (logical shift right, `>>>` in java) must be undone from a persisting sign, as `>>` is an arithmetical shift right, conserving the sign.

The sign bit is the highest bit, but I believe Swift has both 32 and 64 bit ints.
There might be some constant, like java's Integer.MIN_VALUE (int.min?). One could also use a signed int and shift the signBit to the right until it becomes negative.

In general UInt64 would be best to use (`>>` then shifting in a bit 0).

Comment: I think this might be safer than mine with dealing with the signed bit. 

Comment: @Fogmeister feel free to copy. (1) I need no points. (2) your Swift is better and more complete anyhow. (3) int.min == 0b10000..00000 for the sign bit might be available in Swift? You took the UInt8 from the official link.

Comment: Although I'm not actually using signed integers, this is very helpful, thank you!